# Efficient way to reduce transferred data when working with sensors data on the server?

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, cassandra, datastax-astra

I have a system where a **sensor** (owned by someone) sends the data about the outside temperature to my **server (Spring Boot)**, then my server saves the data into **Cassandra database** (hosting at DataStax Astra).

Now I want to implement an algorithm (preferably in Python, could be Java, since my server is in Java), which should be run every time a server receives data from specific sensor (could be every minute). This algorithm uses all of the sensor's previous data (could be yearly data, which results in 525K records). It could be heavy loaded, not sure exact complexity of it.

**The problem** is that I cannot find a great solution to reduce transferred data - the most inefficient solution is to download all sensor records each time a server receives data from that sensor. For each sensor it could be 80 MB (yearly data) and to download this every minute does not seem logical.

I was thinking about caching the data in my server and performing the algorithm execution there or creating some sort of different micro-service. But is it a good approach to cache the data of each sensor on the server? What if there was 500K sensors with 525K records each?

Maybe I am missing knowledge about currently existing PaaS/SaaS service, which could greatly help me in solving this problem. Thus, I am seeking any help - whether it's a library, a service, a recommendation or anything to solve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: I'm guessing you could probably use CDC for Astra to send info on the mutations through a real-time data pipeline.  That way you could avoid the need to transfer the data, but instead, have continuously updated data streams processed by Pulsar, which you could send back to Cassandra or anywhere else that could process Pulsar event streams.  I'm no expert on this, but it might be something to look into.